# Within group_by, mutate a new column that grabs values of a column based on their order of appearance

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm wrangling a dataset that has a cross-over trial design. Here is a toy example with similar structure:

```r
df <- structure(list(subject = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), treatment = c("none", 
"placebo", "placebo", "drug", "drug", "drug", "none", "drug", 
"placebo", "placebo", "none", "placebo", "drug", "drug", "drug", 
"drug"), day = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

```r
# A tibble: 16 × 3
   subject treatment   day
   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
 1 a       none          0
 2 a       placebo       1
 3 a       placebo       2
 4 a       drug          3
 5 a       drug          4
 6 a       drug          5
 7 b       none          0
 8 b       drug          1
 9 b       placebo       2
10 b       placebo       3
11 c       none          0
12 c       placebo       1
13 c       drug          2
14 c       drug          3
15 c       drug          4
16 c       drug          5
```

So, every subject starts with a "none" value in `treatment`, and then has a few days of either `placebo` or a `drug` treatment, followed by a few days of the other.
What I want is a new `stage` column that tells me the chronological stage of the experiment based on the order of `treatment` value. In other words, the starting `none` value in a subject will always be the "first" stage of the experiment, the next chronologically appearing value in `treatment` within that subject will be "second" stage, and the last appearing value will be the "third" stage.

So the output I want would look like this:

```r
# A tibble: 16 × 4
   subject treatment   day stage 
   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <chr> 
 1 a       none          0 first 
 2 a       placebo       1 second
 3 a       placebo       2 second
 4 a       drug          3 third 
 5 a       drug          4 third 
 6 a       drug          5 third 
 7 b       none          0 first 
 8 b       drug          1 second
 9 b       placebo       2 third 
10 b       placebo       3 third 
11 c       none          0 first 
12 c       placebo       1 second
13 c       drug          2 third 
14 c       drug          3 third 
15 c       drug          4 third 
16 c       drug          5 third
```

What made sense to me was using a combination of `group_by` and `mutate` with a `factor` of `treatment`, which doesn't work

```r
#my failed attempt
df %>% 
  arrange(subject, day) %>% #needed for my actual dataset
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  mutate(stage=factor(treatment, levels=c("first", "second", "third"))) %>% 
  ungroup(
```

which gives:

```r
# A tibble: 16 × 4
   subject treatment   day stage 
   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <fct> 
 1 a       none          0 second
 2 a       placebo       1 third 
 3 a       placebo       2 third 
 4 a       drug          3 first 
 5 a       drug          4 first 
 6 a       drug          5 first 
 7 b       none          0 second
 8 b       drug          1 first 
 9 b       placebo       2 third 
10 b       placebo       3 third 
11 c       none          0 second
12 c       placebo       1 third 
13 c       drug          2 first 
14 c       drug          3 first 
15 c       drug          4 first 
16 c       drug          5 first
```

The problem is that the labels are being shown based on the alphabetic order of the "treatment" values, but I want them to appear in the order of appearance of the `treatment` values within each subject. I also tried with `levels` instead of `labels` and I just get all `NA`s.

Any help would be much appreciated. A `dplyr` solution is preferred but would happily work with any other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `group_by` subject and then use `match` or `rleid`. Use `english::ordinal` to get the expected output.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  mutate(match = match(treatment, unique(treatment)),
         rleid = data.table::rleid(treatment),
         stage = english::ordinal(match))

# A tibble: 16 × 6
# Groups:   subject [3]
   subject treatment   day match rleid stage       
   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <int> <int> <ordinal>
 1 a       none          0     1     1 first    
 2 a       placebo       1     2     2 second   
 3 a       placebo       2     2     2 second   
 4 a       drug          3     3     3 third    
 5 a       drug          4     3     3 third    
 6 a       drug          5     3     3 third    
 7 b       none          0     1     1 first    
 8 b       drug          1     2     2 second   
 9 b       placebo       2     3     3 third    
10 b       placebo       3     3     3 third    
11 c       none          0     1     1 first    
12 c       placebo       1     2     2 second   
13 c       drug          2     3     3 third    
14 c       drug          3     3     3 third    
15 c       drug          4     3     3 third    
16 c       drug          5     3     3 third
```

Comment: Thank you, both `match` and `rleid` certainly work on my current dataset, however, the `rleid` approach does have the benefit of not running into the issue described by @Dan below, I checked. Appreciate your time!

Comment: Thank you, both `match` and `rleid` certainly work on my current dataset, however, the `rleid` approach does have the benefit of not running into the issue described by @Dan below, I checked. Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2):

If there is any case where the placebo is given again after the drug, creating a "fourth" stage, then depending on `unique(treatment)` might lead to errors.

Alternatively, you could calculate the cumulative sum of the treatment change:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    group_by(subject) %>% 
    mutate(stage_change = treatment!=lag(treatment), 
           stage = cumsum(ifelse(is.na(stage_change), 1, stage_change))) %>% 
    select(-stage_change)
#> # A tibble: 16 x 4
#> # Groups:   subject [3]
#>    subject treatment   day stage
#>    <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 a       none          0     1
#>  2 a       placebo       1     2
#>  3 a       placebo       2     2
#>  4 a       drug          3     3
#>  5 a       drug          4     3
#>  6 a       drug          5     3
#>  7 b       none          0     1
#>  8 b       drug          1     2
#>  9 b       placebo       2     3
#> 10 b       placebo       3     3
#> 11 c       none          0     1
#> 12 c       placebo       1     2
#> 13 c       drug          2     3
#> 14 c       drug          3     3
#> 15 c       drug          4     3
#> 16 c       drug          5     3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can then use `english::ordinal(stage)` if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I checked your concern by adding placebo again to a group and while the `unique(treatment)` approach runs without errors, you are correct that it wasn't the desired outcome, as the second `placebo` gets recycled as `second` again, however, @Mael's `rleid` approach works just fine. I do like your approach here as it doesn't rely on data.table for the one line, even though slightly bulkier. Thanks for your time!